# Dual boot Windows 10 partition has become non-bootable. How can I make it bootable again?

Tags: windows-10, multi-boot, grub, mbr, gpt

I have a Dell Precision laptop with Windows 10 Professional on a pair of partitions on the main (MBR, 480 GB) SSD. Under linux they show as /dev/sda1 (576 MB NTFS) and /dev/sda2 (43 GB NTFS). They originally consumed the whole of the disk, before I shrank at least the second to make room for linux. When I first installed Linux I verified the ability to dual boot. Over time, the Windows 10 installation has lost that ability to boot, and I am looking for help to recover it.

The disk now has an extended partition /dev/sda3 containing a linux swap partition /dev/sda5 and an XFS partition /dev/sda6 mounted at /home. Linux boots from a smaller MBR SSD /dev/sdb which has /boot, /var and / partitions.

I have two entries for Windows 10 in my GRUB boot list (inserted automatically by update-grub), but they don't work.

I suspect that /dev/sda has got converted from GPT to MBR somewhere along the line.

How can I verify that is the problem, before I attempt anything perhaps harmful by eg converting /dev/sda from MBR to GPT format?

I have tried creating a Windows 10 Recovery USB key (and set the BIOS to boot it in UEFI mode) but it does not boot.

Thanks
Graham

Comment: Use the Windows 10 USB to repair the boot. After that you have to use the Linux USB to repair the Linux installation. If you fail to repair windows, you will still need to repair Linux, because that will kill the Linux bootloader.

Comment: Thanks CFCBazar, but I have never managed to get a Windows Recovery USB to boot, whether in legacy or UEFI modes.

Comment: You are probably using NTFS for the usb instead of fat32 on a uefi enabled system and you have not disabled secure boot in the BIOS.

Comment: I have found the smaller SSD from which I transferred the NTFS and linux partitions. I can boot Windows 10 from it, and it is in MBR format, so I think I can eliminate MBR vs UEFI as a cause of problems. I have tried again to clone the NTFS partitions from old to new drive, again without being able to boot the result. That means I have now tried dd, gparted and Clonezilla to clone these partitions, all without success.

Comment: After cloning the Linux partitions on the new drive you have to repair the Linux grub bootloader. It's done through a live Ubuntu USB by installing boot-repair. You need to clone only the Linux partitions on the new drive. The bootloader always remains on the main drive. Windows can not run from a usb drive.

Comment: The USB key partition type is "W95 FAT32 (LBA) (Bootable)". The content was created by Windows 10 as a Recovery drive.

Comment: Use Rufus and set to MBR and fat32.

Comment: Thanks again for your help CFCBazar. I have fired up boot-repair a couple of times but baulked because it seems too 'black box'. I have never had a problem booting linux. I always run update-grub after attempting to clone, so that the grub config is as correct as it can be.

Comment: Thanks again. I don't know Rufus. What are you suggesting I set to MBR and FAT32? Is that the recovery USB? It is already FAT32, and I have tried booting from it in MBR mode, without success.

Comment: When I say I can't get the USB key to boot, what happens is that I get as far as the blue Windows 10 logo, but never as far as the spinning dots.

Comment: You have to wait at least 5 min maybe 10, it seems your computer is slow.

Comment: You can join the Support chat room that I created and we can continue there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107636/discussion-between-cfcbazar-com-and-graham).